# How do I crawl a .mobi ebook with python?

Tags: python, package

I need to create a python dictionary pickle out of a .mobi ebook. Unfortunately, mobi dictionary files cannot be converted into epub formats, due to some structure issue, as stated by many file converters.

Which python package can be used to crawl the entire data of a mobi file, preserving its data structures?

Comment: https://github.com/kroo/mobi-python

Comment: @FarhadMortezapour in python 3.7.1, on typing "pip install mobi" windows cmd gives the error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mobi (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mobi"

Comment: I know for a fact that mobi can be converted to epub:  https://mobi2epub.com/  that doesn't work for dictionary files??

Comment: @Thufir Its been 2 years since I asked this question. I don't exactly remember how I solved it, but it was sorted out. Thanks for your comment, chill!

And yes, after the conversion, the structure is lost, you can't crawl them systematically anymore.